# Laravel. Фунция динамического вызова scope модели

Tags: php, laravel, scope

Не удается вызвать scope модели через такую функцию. Возможно ли как-то реализовать?

```
$objects = $this->getScope("My");

public function getScope($scope, $parameters = false) {
        if($parameters) {
            $result = $this->model->{$scope($parameters)}->get();
        } else {
            $result = $this->model->{$scope()}->get();
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Ошибка: Call to undefined function my()

Answer (score 0):

Scope в моделях работает [по-другому](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#global-scopes).

В самой модели:

```
public function scopeMy()
{
    //some code
}
```

И обратиться можно `$model->my()`

Comment: Я знаю, что так работает. Хотел сделать универсальный метод для вызова scope у модели.

Comment: @Trick тогда проверяй is_callable или method_exists